# If I use array.shift() on this.state.array, should I use setState after?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I run

```
this.state={
    myArray: [1,2,3,4]
}

let element = this.state.myArray.shift()
```

then `this.state.myArray` will be `[2,3,4]`.

I understand the recommendation is to use `setState` to avoid race conditions, but since `shift()` has already done the shifting, it seems unecessary to use `setState` afterwards.

Is this OK or is there a recommended way to deal with shifting?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] rather than this small stub of pseudocode. What are you trying to achieve? `setState` isn't used to avoid race conditions, it's used to rerender your component. Mutating state directly doesn't trigger a rerender.

Comment: From the title "If I use array.shift() on this.state.array, should I use setState after?" it should be clear it's a question on best practice. Do you really need to reproduce and run an example to comment on best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary.

This code is buggy by definition, as you have mutated the state without going through `setState` -- which is explicitly not allowed in react. That means a re-render will not be triggered, and so anything in render that uses this piece of state will not recalculate, and the DOM displayed to the user will not change.

Use:

```
this.setState(prev => ({ myArray: prev.myArray.slice(1) }))
```

Note `slice` does not modify `this.state.myArray` directly like `shift` does, it returns a new copy with the first item removed.

Comment: Use the callback version if you're reading state: `this.setState(prev => ({ myArray: prev.myArray.slice(1) }))`

Comment: OK, so if I use `shift` as per my example, I would simply use `setState(myarray: modifiedArray)` (after storing it as a new variable)?

Comment: If you really wanted to use `shift()` for some reason (I can't see a good reason to do so as picking a method that implicitly mutates in react is just creating more work for yourself for no good reason), you would need to make a shallow clone of the array, and then use it -- assigning it a new var wouldnt work either as that would just create a new reference to that same array and not a copy (calling shift on it would still be mutating the original array).

Comment: @adsy I meant I would run setState on the mutated (original) array, after mutation. I want to remove the first index of the array (other items are being appended to it, I don't currently don't how long the array will get - shift should be faster than slicing if the array gets really long (allegedly).

Comment: Basically, you can't run setState on the mutated version of the array, because its too late, you've already violated react by mutating it without using setState if that makes sense. It has to be immutable in a way that is atomic. At no stage can you mutate `this.state`, even if your intention is to immediately pipe it into `setState`. Doing so may look like its working, but is definitely bad practice, and will lead to hard to find non-deterministic behaviours later.

Comment: To use shift you'd have to do `const newArray = [...this.state.myArray]` and then `newArray.shift()`. But also, the shallow array clone is likely to be a a much bigger perf issue than using slice.

Comment: Also presuming you need to use this array by looping over it anyways in render (?), I wouldnt worry about the perf impact of this. If it really was a problem, you'd likely want a more advanced data structure than an array like a queue or something. But don't optimize too early.

Comment: It makes perfect sense - I'll avoid using splice and shift then. Aappreciate the detailed answers and leave performance optimisation until the end