Smooth scroll stops working whenever I update the state of an array?
I have a react component that is supposed to working like a rolling queue of the last 5 messages in a discord server. Whenever I reach 5 messages in the queue, I pop the first object from from my array with .shift(), and add my new message to the end.
My problem is, for the first 5 messages, I am able to see them smoothly scroll. However, once I exceed that limit, and the code starts calling .shift() on my array, the smooth scroll stops working.
    ws.addEventListener("message", data => {
    if (messages.length > 5) {
        setMessages(messages.shift());

    }
    setMessages([...messages, JSON.parse(data.data)]);                                                   
});
const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)
useEffect(() => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
}, [messages]);

const MessageList = ({ messages }) => (
    <ul class="">
        {messages.map(message => <DiscordMessage messageData={message}/>)}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef}/>    
    </ul>
)

I tested it without if (messages.length > 5) and it worked as it should. So I think the problem is is whenever I am calling that line of code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085744/18423808 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799424/18423808
May answer your question, seems like setting state with shift isn't ideal.

God bless thank you @IndexZero, it wasn't the exact solution, but the root cause was correct.
if (messages.length >= 5) {
        setMessages([...messages.slice(1,messages.length), JSON.parse(data.data)])
    } else {
        setMessages([...messages, JSON.parse(data.data)]);
    }

I was trying to modify the array directly by calling array.shift(). I am not exactly sure why, but this was ultimately the solution that resolved it.
